# Remove formatting from all spaces in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

What is the easiest way to remove the formatting from all spaces in a Word document?

I am processing the data in a Word document and I can't have spaces with bold or italic etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
While Selection.Find.Execute(" ")
    Selection.ClearFormatting
Wend
```